# Foreign Key value not inserting in entity framework code first approach

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

I have profile table model

```
     public class Profile
        {

            [Key]
            [ForeignKey("User")]
            public string Id { get; set; }
            [DisplayName("First Name")]

            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            [DisplayName("Last Name")]

            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public byte[] ProfileImage { get; set; }
            [DisplayName("Select File to Upload")]
            [NotMapped]

            public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }

            public virtual Address address { get; set; }

            public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

        }
```

and an address table like this

```
 public class Address
        {
            [Key]
            public int Address_Id { get; set; }
            [DisplayName("Address Line1")]
            [MaxLength(50)]
            public string Line1 { get; set; }
            [DisplayName("Address Line2")]
            [MaxLength(50)]

            public string Line2 { get; set; }
            [DisplayName("Address Line3")]
            [MaxLength(50)]

            public string Line3 { get; set; }
            [DisplayName("Postal Code")]

            public string PostalCode { get; set; }
            [DisplayName("Phone")]

            public string Phone { get; set; }
            [DisplayName("Zip Code")]

            public string ZipCode { get; set; }
            [DisplayName("Select Country")]

            public virtual Country country { get; set; }
            [DisplayName("Select Region")]

            public virtual Region region { get; set; }

            [DisplayName("Select City")]

            public virtual City city { get; set; }


        }
```

I have a edit razor view which will edit profile table
@model HelpingHands.Models.Profile

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Profile</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @if (ViewBag.ImageData != null)
                {
                    <img src="@ViewBag.ImageData" id="blah" width="200" class="img-rounded" height="200" />
                }
                else
                {
                    <img src="~/Content/select.jpg" id="blah" class="img-rounded" width="300" height="300" />
                }
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.File, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })


                <input type="file" name="File" id="imgInp" class="form-control" />

                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.File, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.address.Line1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.address.Line1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.address.Line1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.address.Line2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">

                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.address.Line2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.address.Line2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.address.Line3, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">

                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.address.Line3, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.address.Line3, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.address.PostalCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.address.PostalCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.address.PostalCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.address.Phone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.address.Phone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.address.Phone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.address.ZipCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.address.ZipCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.address.ZipCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.address.country.CountryName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("Country", null, "Select Your Country", new { @class = "form-control" })   
                  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.address.country.CountryName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.address.region.RegionName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select class="form-control" id="ddlRegion" name="Region"></select>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.address.region.RegionName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.address.city.CityName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select class="form-control" id="ddlCity" name="City"></select>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.address.city.CityName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh glyphicon-refresh-animate"></span> Save</button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")


}
```

When I posted the form , value of city , country and region value are null

[image]

Need help what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try with `@Html.EditorFor(model => Model.address.Phone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })`. With Capital M.

Comment: What *exactly* do you send to the view?

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss something. I don't see any Foreign key property referring to those tables: city,country etc, not even one referring to your address table. I think that might be your problem. I recently started with .NET but I would recommend you try that. For ex: in the Address class put a property named: CityID and assign the id of the selected city and EF will do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

There is no code to fill out these values.

For Country you pass null.

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Country", null, "Select Your Country", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

For Region and City there are nothing filled out too.

```
<select class="form-control" id="ddlRegion" name="Region"></select>

<select class="form-control" id="ddlCity" name="City"></select>
```

That is why you get null values when the form is posted.

**EDIT:** If you fill it out later then you should just use correct names for select elements. Not just "Country", "Region" and "City", but "address.country.CountryName", "address.region.RegionName", "address.city.CityName".

Actually the values are posted but they do not get to the Profile object. You can see them in "Watch" window for this.Request.Form.AllKeys.

Comment: I am filling country with jquery ajax , then on country change region filled up , then on region change event city filled up.

Comment: I have updated the answer taking into account the new information

Answer (score 0):

You not rendering any controls for properties `City`, `Country` or `Region` so nothing posts back and they will be `null`. Manually creating html for your dropdownlists will almost always lead to problems. In you case you have (for `Country`)

```
<select name="Country" ...>
```

which has no relationship with your model because `Profile` does not contain a property named `Country`. To bind it would need to be

```
<select name="address.country.CountryName" ...>
```

although it unclear exactly which property of `address.country` you need to bind to (surely it would be an ID property), and in any case all this will fail if the properties of `Country` contain any validation attributes. Also including `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.address.country.CountryName` is a bit pointless since you will not get client side validation because your manually generating the html and not including the `data-val-` attributes.

All this will be solved by using a view model and properly generating your html with strongly typed html helpers

```
public class AddressVM
{
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a country")]
  public int? SelectedCountry { get; set; }
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a region")]
  public int? SelectedRegion { get; set; }
  ....
  public SelectList CountryList { get; set; }
  public SelectList RegionList { get; set; }
  ....
}
public class ProfileVM
{
  public ProfileVM()
  {
    Address = new AddressVM();
  }
  ....
  public AddressVM Address { get; set; }
  ....
}
```

Then in the controller

```
ProfileVM model = new ProfileVM();
model.Address.CountryList = new SelectList(db.Countries, "ID", "Name");
// assume this will be populated using client side based on selected country
model.Address.RegionList = new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<Region>());
return View(model);
```

and in the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Address.SelectedCountry, Model.Address.CountryList, "Select Your Country")
@HtmlValidationMessageFor(m => m.Address.SelectedCountry)

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Address.SelectedRegion, Model.Address.RegionList, "Select Your Country")
@HtmlValidationMessageFor(m => m.Address.SelectedRegion)
```

Comment: Thanks what about saving the data will                db.Entry(profilemodel).State = EntityState.Modified;
will update the address table also ?

Comment: If you use a view models (which you should be doing), then in the POST method you need to get the data model and then map the properties from the view model to the data model, then save the data model.